# "Extract Method" highlights wrong place for name change

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Reproduce by creating a new WPF (.Net 6.0) application in Visual Studio 2022 (17.1.6, but was like this before too) and then highlighting the whole `InitializeComponent();` line by clicking to its left

[image]

then click CTRL+R CTRL+M

This is what happens:

[image]

And this is what happens when typing there:

[image]

How do we fix this?

Comment: Under the same version, I tested the same problem as you. It is recommended that you could report the problem in the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/home).

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT Please feel free to do this as you already saw the problem.